# Display WooCommerce product category on shop page (on every product)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display the category of every product on the shop page. Ideally under the image.
Can anyone help, please?
Thanks[image]

Comment: You'll have to edit the Shop template (product post type archive).  But are you using a third party theme, a child theme, a custom theme... ...we don't know.  You need to include some sort of code snippets.  There's often a myriad of ways that an end result can be attained, so just showing a screen capture won't put anyone in a position to give you a concise answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.